# Find index of objects in an array with same name, sort them by value, then change their values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops, object

I'm really stuck at the end of my code, this a snippet of where I get lost. My goal was to create an array of objects from a class I made (not shown) called Books. It stores their ISBN, title, and price. The code is supposed to ask a user for a book title and ISBN # and if it matches any of the books in the array, all the books with the same ISBN and title will be sorted from the lowest price to the highest, and then all of their prices will be changed to the price of the book with the lowest price. I commented where I get lost. Thanks a lot!

The books class looks like this:
    class Books {
            private String title;
            private int ISBN;
            private int price;

```
        public Books(){
            title = "The Outsiders";
            ISBN = 1234;
            price = 14;
        }

        //regular constructor
        public Books(String T, int I, int P){
            title = T;
            ISBN = I;
            price = P;
        }
        //Copy Constructor
        public Books(Books aBook){
            this.title = aBook.title;
            this.ISBN = aBook.ISBN;
            this.price = aBook.price;
        }
```

This is the beginning of my class I'm working in:

```
        //Beginning of ModifyBooks Class
    Books[] Library = new Books[10];

    Library[0] = new Books("blah", 1726374, 12.00);
    Library[1] = new Books("Lovely Bones", 111112, 20.00);
    Library[2] = new Books("Birds in a Fence", 111113, 13.00);
    Library[3] = new Books("Hunger Games", 111114, 14.50);
    Library[4] = new Books("Titanic", 738394, 12.5);
    Library[5] = new Books("Heroes", 7373849, 21.00);
    Library[6] = new Books(Library[1]);
    Library[7] = new Books(Library[1]);
    Library[8] = new Books(Library[2]);
    Library[9] = new Books(Library[3]);

    //Changing all prices of books
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Library.length ; i++){
        Library[i].price = i + 5;
    }

    //Keyboard configuration
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a book's title:");
    String UserTitle = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter a book's ISBN Number:");
    int UserISBN = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Your entered book's title is " + UserTitle + " and the ISBN is " + UserISBN);

    double[] sameBook = new double[10];
    int counter = 0;
```

This is where my code doesn't do what I want it to, I have no clue how to make it do what I described above but here's my attempt.

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Library.length ; i++ ){
        if (UserTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(Library[i].title) && UserISBN == Library[i].ISBN){
            sameBook[i] = Library[i].price;
            counter++;
        } 
        else {
            sameBook[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    double[] SmallerLibrary = new double[counter];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < sameBook.length ; i++){
        if (sameBook[i] != 0){
            SmallerLibrary[i] = sameBook[i];
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(SmallerLibrary);

}
```

}

Comment: The last for loop doesn't achieve what I want it to but I have no clue how to fix it. I better clarified the problem above.

Comment: I assume that you have two different constructors for Books, one that accepts 3 parms and one that accepts 1 parm that is another Books object?

Comment: you are comparing UserISBN (which is coming as string when input by user) with integer ISBN of the array. Did you convert the userinput to integer before comparing the two ISBNs ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following strategy:

1. Iterate through every book object in the array and check to see if it matches the user input.
2. If the book is a match, store it's index in an array for later use and update the value for a global min price variable if the book has a lower price than what it was previously set to (control it's initial value for the first pass case)
3. Once you have finished iterating through the list, use the array storing the indexes for each of the matching books and update their price fields with the global min price variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are iterating over arrays with different lengths causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

If you input "Lovely Bones", 111112, then you would have 3 matches.

sameBook length is always 10.

```
double[] sameBook = new double[10];
```

But SmallerLibrary length would be 3 (initialized with counter)

```
double[] SmallerLibrary = new double[counter];
```

So when iterating over sameBook.length the index will eventually be larger than SmallerLibrary.length causing the exception.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < sameBook.length ; i++){
    if (sameBook[i] != 0){
        SmallerLibrary[i] = sameBook[i];  // Exception thrown here
    }
}
```

You would need a separate index for the values in SmallerLibrary.

```
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sameBook.length; i++) {
     if (sameBook[i] != 0) {
        SmallerLibrary[j++] = sameBook[i];
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, I figured out how to make my program do what I wanted with help from Jeff Ward and Phillip. The new WORKING code is below! :)

```
    //Beginning of ModifyBooks Class
    Books[] Library = new Books[10];

    Library[0] = new Books();
    Library[1] = new Books("Lovely Bones", 12345, 20);
    Library[2] = new Books("Birds in a Fence", 123456, 13);
    Library[3] = new Books("Hunger Games", 1234567, 14);
    Library[4] = new Books("Titanic", 12345678, 12);
    Library[5] = new Books("Heroes", 123456789, 21);
    Library[6] = new Books(Library[0]);
    Library[7] = new Books(Library[0]);
    Library[8] = new Books(Library[2]);
    Library[9] = new Books(Library[3]);

    //Changing all prices of books
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Library.length ; i++){
        Library[i].price = i + 5;
    }

    //Keyboard configuration
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Getting user information
    System.out.println("Please enter a book's title:");
    String UserTitle = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter a book's ISBN Number:");
    int UserISBN = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Your entered book's title is " + UserTitle + " and the ISBN is " + UserISBN);

    int[] sameBook = new int[10]; //new array that will carry the index of each match
    int counter = 0; //tracks number of matches
    int globalMin = 200; //lowest price for the matches books, initialized at 200 so the program functions properly


    //Finding the matches in main array, and casting their indexes in another array
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Library.length ; i++ ){
        if (UserTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(Library[i].title) && UserISBN == Library[i].ISBN){
            sameBook[i] = i;
            counter++;
                if (Library[i].price < globalMin){
                    globalMin = Library[i].price;
                }
        }
        else {
            sameBook[i] = 0;
        }

    }

    //Creating a new array that only contains the amount of matches there are, containing their indexes
    int[] smallerLibrary = new int[counter];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < sameBook.length ; i++){
        if (sameBook[i] != 0){
            smallerLibrary[j++] = sameBook[i];
        }
    }

    //Text notifying user of matches and telling the, what the new prices will be
    for (int i = 0 ; i < smallerLibrary.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("Index number [" + smallerLibrary[i] + "] matches both the ISBN and title. The price was $" + Library[smallerLibrary[i]].price + " and is being changed to the lowest price of $" + globalMin + ".");
    }

    //Changing the prices from the matches to the lowest prices
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Library.length ; i++){
        if (UserTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(Library[i].title) && UserISBN == Library[i].ISBN){
        Library[i].price = globalMin;
        System.out.println("Change was made for index number "+i+".");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?